# How to set up so `git pull` does what `git pull origin master` does?

Tags: git, github

I just want to be able to write:

```
$ git pull
// does the same as $ git pull origin master
$ git push 
// does the same as $ git push origin master
```

Except currently when I do `$ git pull` I get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: The answer is in the question.

Comment: Please consider taking 15 seconds to actually _read_ the output of `git pull` that you pasted into your question. Git commands can generate confusing output, but I think this is an example of exceptionally clear feedback.

Comment: I don't appreciate your disparaging comment @Chris. Please take the time to be patient with new beginners like me, who find terminal outputs overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

It says so right there in the error message:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

Assuming, of course, that you're on branch `master` locally as well.

What does setting the upstream mean?

> Checking out a local branch from a remote-tracking branch
>   automatically creates what is called a “tracking branch” (and the
>   branch it tracks is called an “upstream branch”). Tracking branches
>   are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch.
>   If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically
>   knows which server to fetch from and branch to merge into

Source: [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: Could you explain what `upstream` is?

Comment: I'll leave that to [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: And what the command  `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` means?

Comment: I'll leave that to [the `git branch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).